# How do I make scalable PHP for rapid Ajax requests?

Tags: php, html

I have a program in which an Ajax request goes out to a PHP script that does all the behind the scenes stuff of grabbing the data from the database and then returning it as responseText to be pasted into my HTML to update the page without refreshing.  I do this request once every 250 milliseconds (so that means I get 4 hits to the PHP script per second for every user on the HTML page firing the Ajax requests.)  I am already seeing the PHP crash with a few computers on at the same time, so I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the PHP getting a lot of requests.  Is there a way to do these requests so that a lot of users can get on without this scalability issue coming into play?

Comment: Why does it need to do it 4 times a second? What returned HTML needs to update that often?

Comment: How often would you recommend a request being fired?

Comment: It depends entirely on the requirements. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Is pushing (instead of pulling) the data an option? If so, look at "reverse Ajax".

Comment: Yeah, consider using comet servers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

First of all firing that much ajax requests ain't a good idea. when the number of users increases, the server load will increase exponentially serving requests. Second thing  you need to consider the possibilities of scaling the application and database. I guess you might be returning json_encoded data from server, else make it so.

Answer (score -1):

4 r/s is.. nothing for PHP. So in a short: in order to make PHP scalable; make your code scalable.

Comment: Depends entirely on what is involved with each request.

Comment: That's 4 requests per second -per user- if I read his question properly. This doesn't change your answer's merit, but is worth pointing out.

Comment: @alex that's exactly my point. Perhaps comprehension needs to be acquired on your end.